# Suppose $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. Prove that $g \circ f: A \rightarrow C$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. Prove that $g
>  \circ f: A \rightarrow C$

My attempt:

Definition of the composition (according to the book I'm reading):

> $$g \circ f = \{(a,c) \in A \times C \mid \exists d \in B((a,d) \in f \land
>  (d,c) \in g)\}$$

Take $a \in A$. There exists some $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. Since $g: B \rightarrow C$ and $b \in B$, there also exists some $c \in C$ such that $(b,c) \in g$. By definition of the composition of the relations, we have $(a,c) \in g \circ f$. Hence for all $a \in A$, there is at least one $c \in C$ such that $g \circ f$.

Now we prove uniqueness.

Suppose $(a,x) \in g \circ f $ and $(a,y) \in g \circ f$.

Then there exists some $d$ such that $(a,d) \in f$ and $(d,x) \in g$.

And there also exists some $v$ such that $(a,v) \in f$ and $(v,y) \in g$.

We have $(a,d) \in f$ and $(a,v) \in f$. By definition of the functions, we conclude that $d = v$.

Hence for all $a \in A$, there exists *unique* $c \in C$ such that $(a,c) \in g \circ f$.

Therefore, $g \circ f$ is a function from $A$ to $C$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: What is your definition of composite functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Only thing I can suggest is to label the first subproof as "proof of (left-)totality".